# Gateway in the other side of a VPN

Tags: linux, iptables, vpn

I've 2 linux machines connected via an ipsec VPN.
[PC1] can ping [4G-GW] correctly.

I need to permit [PC1] to navigate via [4G-GW] in the other side of VPN.

So, i've tryed to add an additional ip to interface of left GW with

`ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.1.11`
and configured [PC1] to use GW 192.168.1.11.

I've added this rules:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.2/32 -d 192.168.1.11/32 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.2`

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.2/32 -d 192.168.1.2/32 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.11`

Ping from [PC1] to [4G-GW] is ok but [PC1] cannot navigate.

What is the problem?
Thank you

-- edit as required:

[PC1]:

```
ip route show
default via 192.168.1.11 dev eth0
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo scope link

192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.2
```

[GW1]:

```
root:~# ip route show
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo scope link 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.4 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.1
```

[GW2]:

```
root:~# ip route show
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo scope link 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.4 
192.168.2.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.1
```

The 4G router is a hw device.
[layout_with_fiber_routers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHmXN.jpg)

-- UPDATE
[GW1] and [GW2] enstabilish VPN

[GW1](host vpnhome)

```
root@vpnhome:~# ipsec status
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
sinigo-to-home[9]: ESTABLISHED 28 minutes ago, 192.168.0.4[aaaa.ns0.it]...87.A.A.A[xxxx]
sinigo-to-home{9}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 1, ESP in UDP SPIs: cea445de_i cb317c99_o
sinigo-to-home{9}:   192.168.1.0/24 === 192.168.2.0/24

root@vpnhome:~# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.4  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::8639:beff:fe6d:d17e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 84:39:be:6d:d1:7e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 44320  bytes 3064750 (2.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 9  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9686  bytes 734844 (717.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::8639:beff:fe6d:d17f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 84:39:be:6d:d1:7f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 429  bytes 57346 (56.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 744  bytes 72568 (70.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1:1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.11  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether 84:39:be:6d:d1:7f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

i don't see VPN interfaces

[GW2](host vpnsinigo)

```
root@vpnsinigo:~# ipsec status
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
sinigo-to-home[54]: ESTABLISHED 31 minutes ago, 192.168.1.4[xxx]...2.Y.Y.Y[yyyyy]
sinigo-to-home{51}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 1, ESP in UDP SPIs: cb317c99_i cea445de_o
sinigo-to-home{51}:   192.168.2.0/24 === 192.168.1.0/24

root@vpnsinigo:~# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.4  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::230:18ff:fe03:c652  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:30:18:03:c6:52  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 228925  bytes 16151386 (15.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 14  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 46461  bytes 4461111 (4.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::230:18ff:fe03:c653  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:30:18:03:c6:53  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 62716  bytes 5404945 (5.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1589  bytes 235272 (229.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Could you please add to the question the routing tables from all 4 machines? The command is: `ip route show`

Comment: The IP 192.168.0.4 for Eth0 on GW1 is the address of physical interface or the VPN interface? Similarly 192.168.1.4 on GW2. What is 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.1.1? I don't see interfaces with these IP addresses anywhere on the diagram.

Comment: Also why machine GW2 has default routing via 192.168.1.1? From your diagram it looks rather than the default route should be 192.168.2.2.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I've updated layout so you can see the complete network diagram

Comment: And what is establishing the VPN tunnel? GW1 and GW2 machines or the fiber routers? If GW1 and GW2, then please provide also the IP addresses of VPN tunnel interfaces...

Comment: GW1 and GW2 estabilish VPN via IPsec

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly from the additional data you provided how your VPN works, it looks that it "directly" (on layer 3 level) connects Eth1 on GW1 to Eth0 on GW2 - they work as if they were on the same subnet. To verify this, try pinging 192.168.1.4 from PC1. If it answers, then you probably can reach GW2 directly from PC1.

So it is possible that NAT rules on GW1 are not applied at all. Maybe to be applied, they should actually be on GW2, not on GW1.

192.168.1.11 replies to ping, but it may well be just the interface `eth1:1` on GW1 that replies to ping. To verify whether you are actually reaching 4G-GW under 192.168.1.11, try to connect from PC1 via this address to router's management panel. If you are actually reaching the router, it should succeed. If not - then it's just GW1 answering and it doesn't forward the connection anywhere.

I'm not sure if you need that NAT at all. If you are able to ping 192.168.1.4 from PC1, try to remove the NAT rules and the `eth1:1` interface altogether and set the default gateway on PC1 to 192.168.1.4. Then check if you are able to ping 192.168.2.2. If this also succeeds, set the default gateway on GW2 to 192.168.2.2. You should be able to reach the Internet from PC1 now.

If it is not possible to change the default gateway on GW2, try setting default gateway on PC1 directly to 192.168.2.2 AND add a route (on PC1 as well) to 192.168.2.2 via 192.168.1.4, to allow PC1 to reach it's gateway.

Please let me know if any of this worked.

Comment: Thank you for the help. First, i've deleted virtual interface 192.168.1.11 on GW1 (there is no motivation to keep it).
PC1 now has gw 192.168.1.1.
From PC1 i can: 
ping 192.168.2.2;
not ping 192.168.1.4 (because PC1 has the same network so it can't ping a host over the vpn with that subnet);
PC1 connects correctly to webinterface of 192.168.2.2.
I cannot change default gw on GW2 because if i change it VPN goes down. How can i set default gw of PC1 via another gw? with what command?

Comment: How do you set the gateways and routes permanently, it depends on what kind of Linux you are using. It may be in the startup scripts, it may be in the Network Manager GUI... I just don't know what are you using.

Comment: To do it **temporarily**, try the following: 1) add route to 192.168.2.2 via 192.168.1.1: `route add -host 192.168.2.2 gw 192.168.1.1`; 2) delete you current default GW: `route del -net default gw 192.168.1.1`; 3) set a new default GW: `route add -net default gw 192.168.2.2`.

Comment: i've done this try (i'm able to modify slackware configurations, no problem). See my answer up

Answer (score 0):

PC1, GW1 and GW2 has slackware.
So i've done for PC1:

- removed default gw
- `route add -host 192.168.2.2 gw 192.168.1.1`

now `route -n` says:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.2.2     192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
```

but when I try to execute

`route add -net default gw 192.168.2.2`

PC1 says

`SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable`

i can ping and connect to web interface of 192.168.2.2 but cannot connect to rest of the world

Comment: Well... that's strange for me. If you previously added a route to 192.168.2.2, then it should be able to add this as a default GW...

Comment: You can try to again add the NAT rules that translate 192.168.1.11 to 192.168.2.2, but this time do it on PC1. (do not create the interface 192.168.1.11, however). If you set the default GW to 192.168.1.11, it might work.

Comment: sorry but i've not understood something: the commands of this answer (removed default gw, route add -host.... etc etc) has been executed on PC1. I've mistaked something?

Comment: "route to 192.168.2.2, then it should be able to add this as a default GW" i've readed that you cannot set a default gw based on a route

Comment: Yes, these command should be executed on PC1. If it is not possible to set the default GW to 192.168.2.2, then try to add on PC1 the same "iptables" rules that you previously added on GW1 (but do not create any interface for 192.168.1.11) and set the default GW to 192.168.1.11